# Why doesn't laravel recognize my model?

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error that says, "No query results for the model [App\dummy]." I believe the problem is in the controller. When you submit the form it is supposed to trigger the function in the comment controller. This controller is new so, I believe the error is in here. That is when it stopped working. Here is the commentController file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Dummy;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; //this one is for sql builders

use App\Comments;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use DateTime; //to create a new date object you need to include this namespace



class commentController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Dummy $post){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    $id = $post->id;

    $post->addComment(request('body'));

    return view('post', compact('post', 'timestamp', 'id'));
  }
}
```

I tried making App\Dummy lowercase so it was App\dummy but still it didn't work. It still gives me the error.

Here is my dummy model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class dummy extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function comments(){
      return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'post_id');

    }

    public function addComment($body){
      $this->comments()->create(compact('body'));
    }
}
```

Comment: show your model file here

Comment: @Kris Roofe I posted my dummy model on the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the form. The action attribute in the form was something like this:

```
<form class="col s12" action={{ url('/post/$id/comments') }} method="post">
```

I thought that would get the id because I compacted the id into the variable $id. But then I checked the url and noticed not a number but the actual word $id. So, here is the solution:

```
<form class="col s12" action={{ url('/post/' . $post->id . '/comments') }} method="post">
```

Just to let you guys know that when it said, "No query results for the model [App\dummy]." It meant that when I used this method from the dummy model which had this line of code:

```
public function comments(){
  return $this->hasMany(Comments::class, 'post_id');
}
```

It couldn't find the primary key from the dummies table. Therefore couldn't connect with the foreign key which is the post_id from the comments table. So, it wasn't able to submit the new comment to the table for that unique blog post. This is the last part that submits the comment to the table:

```
public function addComment($body, $name){
      $this->comments()->create(compact('body', 'name')); 
    }
```

by the way comments() is the method I created that i just showed before.

**Conclusion**

It pretty much stopped working in the web.php file(routing file) because it wasn't getting an id. Due to the mistake I made in the action attribute in the form that i explained before.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that your class is called `dummy` buy you are using it as `Dummy`, so rename it both (file and class) to `Dummy`.

This `class dummy extends Model` to this `class Dummy extends Model`.

Remember that your file should be called `Dummy.php` too, not `dummy.php`

Comment: I just did what you did and made my file called Dummy.php and also changed class dummy extends Model to class Dummy extends Model and it still didn't work :((

Comment: Show us in your question your actual hierarchy, you have something wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

Change your model class name to `Dummy` and file name to `Dummy.php`.

Your main problem here is the route model binding. When you're trying to add a comment, the `$post` object is not getting resolved based on your route. You have bad a route setup or trying to add comment to a non existent post.

Basically the error message `No query results for the model` happens because of this code that the route model binding does for you.

```
$post = Dummy::findOrFail($id);
```

Try changing this

```
Route::post('post/{dummy}/comments', 'commentController@store');

public function store(Dummy $dummy)
```